# In Android how do I change the default application for a particular intent programmatically?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I am writing an Android App which has the following feature : 
When the app is running/started, it should be the default intent handler of one particular intent and when the app is not running the system's default application should be launched...

Comment: I do believe you cannot do that. It is against common (android) philosophy - an application should never be able to do things that costs money for the user or (in this case) changes default behaviour without explicit user permission. However, unless you plan to do something evil, there is nothing bad in making the user check that little box upon the first start, you can ask them to do so if they did not. I would not mind such behaviour as a user.

Answer (score 3):

Fortunately, this is not possible, for obvious security reasons.

You are welcome to enable and disable the activity that contains your specific `<intent-filter>`, using `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()`. However, you cannot make it be the default handler. The user will be presented with a chooser dialog and will be able to make their choice.

Comment: CommonsWare is correct AFIAK. The Android platform is designed so that no application can TAKE control of any aspect.